# Help with manipulating child/parent elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child, dom-manipulation

Currently I have this JQuery script

```
var img = $(this);
img.wrap('<div class="photo"></div>');
img.parent().append("<p>" + img.attr("alt") + "</p>");
```

which successfully turns the following:

```
    <img src="photo.jpg" alt="caption">
```

into this

```
<div class="photo">
    <img src="photos.jpg" alt="caption"/>
        <p>caption</p>
</div>
```

All is well unless the image has a link as a parent; `<a href="#"><img` since I want it to be correct html (I'm fussy) improving the resulting outcome bellow would be satisfactory

```
<a href="#">
<div class="photo">
    <img src="photos.jpg" alt="caption"/>
        <p>caption</p>
</div>
</a>
```

to this:

```
<div class="photo">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="photos.jpg" alt="caption"/>
    </a>
        <p><a href="#">caption</a></p>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery script so far (which doesn't work bc I'm a noob) aha

```
if(img.parent('a')){
    var targetLink = img.parent('a').attr('href').val();
    img.parent('a').wrap('<div class="photo"></div>');
    img.parent('div').append('<p><a href="'+targetLink+'">' + img.attr("alt") + '</p></a>');
}else{
     img.wrap('<div class="photo"></div>');
     img.parent().append("<p>" + img.attr("alt") + "</p>");
};
```

Any advice, or help will be greatly appreciated : )
Thank You!

**Update** **Answer**

```
var withLink = img.parent('a').length > 0,
targetPar = withLink ? img.parent() : img;

targetPar.wrap('<div class="photo"></div>');

if(withLink > 0){
    targetPar.parent().append('<p class="caption"><a href="'+img.parent().attr('href')+'">' + img.attr('title') + '</p></a>');
}else{
    img.parent().append('<p class="caption">' + img.attr('title') + '</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is your "if" statement, which should be:

```
if (img.parent('a').length) {
  // ...
}
```

Then, when you try to get the "href" of the `<a>` tag, you're calling "val()" and that's not necessary (or correct, even):

```
  var targetLink =  img.parent('a').attr('href');
```

Also, though not relevant to your problem, the "alt" attribute is supposed to describe what the image is about, while the "title" is more like what I'd call a "caption".  In other words, the "alt" text should be understandable to people who can't see the image at all, while the "title" describes an image to a person who *can* see it.  Just a nit.;

Comment: hmm, that didn't seem to work. But you made a good point I'll adjust my code to pick up the title instead of the alt attribute : )

Comment: Ah I missed the ".attr('href').val()" - that's wrong, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: and there is one more bit, after I wrap the link element in a `div` the img.parent('div') is no longer existent and should be something like `img.parent('a').parent('div')` which is sloppy but I'll find a better way of writing it now aha.

Comment: @Mohammad instead of using "parent()" you can use "closest()", which will go up the DOM until it finds what you're looking for.

Comment: Pointy, I've updated my answer in the Question space. It looks like a cleaner way to achieve the previous. I'm sure there are JQuery specific more efficient ways of writing the code that use `document.createElement()` and not `innerHTML` but that knowledge is above at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
var img = $(this);
var target = $(img).parent();
if (target.is("a")) {
  target = target.parent();
}
target.wrap("<div>");
var div = target.parent();
div.addClass("photo");
$("<p>").attr("alt", $(img).attr("alt")).appendTo(div);
```

Some browsers are exceptionally slow at using `innerHTML` type methods for markup creation so I tend to favour the above approach, which uses diretc DOM element creation. To clarify, as of jQuery 1.4+ at least:

```
$("<p class='photo'>...</p>')...
```

uses `innerHTML` but:

```
$("<p>").addClass("photo").text("...");
```

uses `document.createElement()`.

Comment: Thank you cletus!  
your code returns the bellow results (almost there but needs a bit of tweaking probably)  
`<div class="photo"><div id="parentDiv"><a href="#"><img src="photo.jpg" alt="caption"></a></div><p alt="caption"></p></div>`
Just that the div that is created with the class 'photo' is placed above the holding parent div, and the p element created is holding an attribute of caption when it should be holding the text 'caption'.

Comment: cletus I'm gonna look and your code and learn to adjust mine to be more efficient and use direct DOM element creation. Thank you!