# jQuery DOM element creation vs innerHTML

Tags: jquery, dom, comparison, innerhtml

While having one of my questions answered, [cletus mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922925/help-with-manipulating-child-parent-elements-with-jquery/2922975#2922975) that when creating elements in jQuery it's better to use *`direct DOM element creation`*, instead of *`innerHTML`*. I tried googling it but I wasn't able to find a good article with comparisons.

I've provided this code bellow as an example and I was wondering if someone could help me rewrite it in direct DOM element creation form in hope that i would also learn the difference afterwards.

```
var img = $(this);
img.append('<p class="cap"><a href="'+img.parent().attr('href')+'">'+
img.attr('title')+'</p></a>');
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Mohammad: @cletus has the reason for that too: *Some browsers are exceptionally slow at using innerHTML type methods for markup creation so I tend to favour the above approach, which uses diretc DOM element creation.*

Comment: There's actually a [performance tool](http://www.developer-x.com/content/innerhtml/dom_vs_innerHTML_perf_test.html) you can test various browsers with. As well, T.J. Crowder wrote a [quick summary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode) of the benefits and drawbacks of innerHTML. I've never personally felt very comfortable using innerHTML, though I have found it faster at clearing the contents of a div than repeatedly removing child nodes. I'm surprised that there's actually good reason to use it. (I don't know why I posted this earlier as an "answer")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, avoid HTML string-slinging. You're giving yourself bugs and potentially cross-site scripting security holes. For example:

```
'<a href="'+img.parent().attr('href')+'">'
```

what if the URL in the parent's `href` contains characters that are special in this HTML context, like `<`, `"` or `&`? At best you'll get invalid markup that might trip the browser up; at worst, if the URL comes from user submission, a security problem.

(OK, `<` and `"` are unlikely to appear in a URL, but `&` is very likely indeed. The `title` you're putting in the text content may be more vulnerable.)

This is a large and increasing problem. Just as we're starting to get a handle on fixing the HTML-injection bugs coming from templating on the server-side (eg. PHP users forgetting to `htmlspecialchars()`), we're now introducing loads of new *client-side* XSS from naïve HTML-hacking with `innerHTML` and jQuery's `html()`. Avoid.

You *can* escape text you're inserting into HTML manually:

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
    return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

'<a href="'+encodeHTML(img.parent().attr('href'))+'">'
```

but really, you're better off using the direct DOM-style properties and methods, which, since they involve no HTML parsing, don't require any escaping. They're called DOM-style because that's the way the original DOM Level 1 HTML features work (which existed back before `innerHTML` reared its ugly head):

```
var a= document.createElement('a');
a.href= this.parentNode.href;
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.title));
```

In jQuery you use `attr()` and `text()` to do the same:

```
var a= $('<a></a>');
a.attr('href', $(this).parent().attr('href');
a.text($(this).attr('title'));
```

And in jQuery 1.4, you can do it most conveniently using an element creation shortcut:

```
$(this).append(
    $('<p class="cap"></p>').append(
        $('<a></a>', {
            href: $(this).parent().attr('href'),
            text: $(this).attr('title')
        })
    )
);
```

This still looks a bit questionable though, what's the parent that you're getting the `href` from? It's invalid to put a `<p>`, or another link, inside a link.

Comment: Thank you! bobince, before I append the `<p>` I wrap the image and it's parent: `<a>` inside a `<div>` which also become the new target as you can see in my update here http://j.mp/bVk1J1

Comment: Regarding that same note, is `targetPar.wrap('<div class="photo"></div>');` the best implementation of this method? Thanks again for your thorough answer!

Comment: Yes, including the static `class="photo"` in the wrapper HTML is fine. `title` is certainly a more appropriate place to put caption-like information than `alt`.

Comment: bobince, I think your last code has a syntax error. It says "missing ) after argument list"

Answer (score 2):

This is how you create elements in jQuery:

```
var myDiv = $('<div class="my-class"></div>');
```

And then you can do all kinds of cool stuff with `myDiv`.

Here it is using your example:

```
var img = $(this);
var myP = $('<p class="cap"></p>');
var myA = $('<a></a>');
myA.attr("href",img.parent().attr('href'));
myA.html(img.attr('title'));
myP.append(myA);
this.append(myP);
```

It's a bit verbose, but yeah.